# Can I search the case lookup field by contact name?

Tags: visualforce, custom-field, case, search

I try to type in a contact name in the case lookup field and it brings up nothing. I need to know if there is a way to search this by name because end users are not going to know account numbers.

Comment: Can you check whether there are any lookup filters on Contact? This you can see by going to Setup>>Build>>Case>>Fields>>Contact Name

Comment: There are no lookup filters on Contact